# VBA: an executable application to read the log file and store the data

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am planning to make an application which can import the data from some files and store them in the relevant tables in (MS Access). However, I realised there might be some issues implementing this as it seems that I can't make an executable application with the specified tables hidden in the application.

For more information: the log files have the same structure and I am aiming to import the relevant columns to the tables and then use those data...

Would be great if you know anyway that I can make an executable application while keeping the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a batch file that will open the database and run a particle query or vba code. All the user would do is double click the he batch file.